# Duplicate class (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1)

Tags: java, android, libraries

I want to know how resolve the error of duplicate dependencies.
I did not have library version 9.6.1. where it comes from?

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.g_track"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'


    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ar-android:DrawRouteMaps:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.cs:googlemaproute:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And it gives me this error. I don't want c`om.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1`

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Comment: probably because of using `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'` and `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'`.
Try 16 or 17 for both

Comment: @Psycho I tried but the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies behind the `implementation 'com.cs:googlemaproute:1.0.0'` dependency which uses `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2` **as one of its dependencies**. To tell Gradle to ignore the second dependency used by `googlemaproute` and use yours you'll have to exclude it from your 3rd party library.

So use:

```
implementation ('com.cs:googlemaproute:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
}
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.cs:googlemaproute:1.0.0'
```

Comment: When ever I add any version of implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:x.x.x' it shows this error. if I remove this dependancy it will work fine. I want to get device's location but due to this error I could not.